# OOP design - inheriting from container with generic type

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance

I have two classes, say `CollectionA` and `CollectionB`, both inheriting from a `Collection`. `Collection` has an `std::array<GenericType>` attribute. I want to use `CollectionA` as a Collection whose inherited `std::array` contains elements of type `ClassA` (`std::array<ClassA>`) and `CollectionB` as containing an `std::array<ClassB>`. Is this possible, and if so how can I implement this design?

Note: I am not familiar with templates, if they are required for this problem.

**EDIT**: `Collection` is user-defined, so I'm not directly inheriting from `std::array`

Comment: You're still going to need templates here :v

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Any way to use them without knowing them inside and out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template would be the obvious solution, start with

```
template<typename Element>
class Collection
{
protected:
    std::array<Element> arrr_;
};

class CollectionA : public Collection<ClassA>
{
};

class CollectionB : public Collection<ClassB>
{
};
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Define them as so

```
class ContainerA : public Container<ClassA> {...};
class ContainerB : public Container<ClassB> {...};
```

Comment: @DanielFrey Good call, habit!

Answer (score 0):

```
  template <class T>
  class Collection {
    protected:
      std::array<T> data_;
  };

  class CollectionA : public Collection<A> {
   /*
    you can use data_ in this class. 
    data_ will be of type std::array<T>;
   */
  };
```

Comment: This is not valid C++. Fix the `class Collection A`.